# Accessing html child elements using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
   <table id="rr" class="table mobile table-bordered">
<tr class="data "  id="abc1235">
  <td>
     <span class="label tip-top files-count" data-original-  title="Filesin">1</span>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1">
     <a class="tname " href="/file/123/0">User12</a>
  </td>
  <td class="tprogress">
     <span class="label size tip-top" data-original-title="Size">18.2   MB</span>
  </td>
  <td>
     <!--actions-->
  </td>
</tr>
 <tr class="data"  id="abc12356">
  <td>
       <span class="label tip-top files-count" data-original-title="Files            in">1</span>
   </td>
   <td colspan="1">
     <a class="tname " href="/file/123/1">Hi user </a>
  </td>
  <td class="tprogress">
       <span class="label size tip-top" data-original-title="Size">18.2MB</span>
   </td>
  <td>
     <!--actions-->
  </td>
</tr>
     </table>
```

Using php i want to get the info in this format 
Name:User12 
id:abcd12345
Name:Hi user 
id:abc12356

So far what i did is

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $link) {

    echo $link->getAttribute('id');
    echo "<br />";
}
```

this only gets first Value i need to go inside and get the text of a tag

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the spurious extra spaces in the html above the following ought to get what you are needing.

```
<?php
    $strhtml='
        <table id="rr" class="table mobile table-bordered">
            <tr class="data" id="abc1235">
              <td>
                 <span class="label tip-top files-count" data-original-title="Filesin">1</span>
              </td>
              <td colspan="1">
                 <a class="tname" href="/file/123/0">User12</a>
              </td>
              <td class="tprogress">
                 <span class="label size tip-top" data-original-title="Size">18.2 MB</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <!--actions-->
              </td>
            </tr>
             <tr class="data" id="abc12356">
              <td>
                   <span class="label tip-top files-count" data-original-title="Files in">1</span>
               </td>
               <td colspan="1">
                 <a class="tname" href="/file/123/1">Hi user</a>
              </td>
              <td class="tprogress">
                   <span class="label size tip-top" data-original-title="Size">18.2MB</span>
               </td>
              <td>
                 <!--actions-->
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>';

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );
    $xpath=new DOMXPath( $dom );

    $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    if( $col ){
        $output=array();
        foreach( $col as $tr ){
            $a_usr=$xpath->query( 'td/a[@class="tname"]', $tr );
            $output[]=array('id'=>$tr->getAttribute('id'), 'user'=>$a_usr->item(0)->nodeValue );
        }

        /* Display what was found */
        echo '<pre>',print_r($output,true),'</pre>';
    }

    /* not really required but tidy up */
    $dom = $xpath = $col = $tr = $output = null;
?>
```

Comment: Nice one , thanks that did worked for me . i dint knw that it can be done in this way